# Once cudaMalloc returns out of memory, every cuda API call returns failure

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

With the CUDA, is it possible to use like a garbage-collection?

For example, when I got an out-of-memory error from `cudaMalloc(...)`, can I free the previously allocated data and retry allocating memory?

Once `cudaMalloc(...)` returns out-of-memory, 
the following cuda calls seem to return the out-of-memory after then.
Even when I call cudaFree with the valid device pointer allocated previously, cudaFree returns out-of-memory...

`cudaDeviceReset()` is not a good way to recover the state for my case.

Comment: When you say (in the title) "every cuda API call returns failure", do you actually "every cudaMalloc call returns failure" (ie. is this question really "cudaFree doesn't seem to free memory", or is it something else)?

Comment: I meant every subsequent call to any cuda API.

Answer (score 6):

Once CUDA encounters an error, all API calls will return that error. If the error corrupts the CUDA context, there's not much to do except reset the device (`cudaDeviceReset`). If the CUDA context has not been corrupted then the state can be [reset](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__ERROR.html#group__CUDART__ERROR_1g3529f94cb530a83a76613616782bd233) to `cudaSuccess` by calling `cudaGetLastError()`.

As per Robert Crovella's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909368/once-cudamalloc-returns-out-of-memory-every-cuda-api-call-returns-failure/30911340?noredirect=1#comment49862179_30911340), a failed `cudaMalloc` probably does not corrupt the CUDA context and therefore you should be able to recover. This is not necessarily true of other causes of an error, and each case may be different.

Comment: This is probably true for this question.  However CUDA runtime API errors come in two flavors: non-sticky errors (CUDA context is still usable) and sticky errors (CUDA context is corrupted).  I would say "The state can be reset (*for non-sticky errors*) to..."   I believe a `cudaMalloc` failure due to out of memory should be a non-sticky (i.e. not corrupting the CUDA context) error.

Comment: @RobertCrovella That was pretty much what I was trying to say in the last sentence. I'll try and incorporate you're  comment in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my case, cudaGetLastError() doesn't recover the situation..

Comment: The I recommend editing your question to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people have more to work with, and to help you determine the exact cause of your problem.

Comment: I think the behavior is pretty much exactly as is described by Avi in this answer.   Ordinary `cudaMalloc` operations return no error.  A `cudaMalloc` operation that runs out of memory will return error 2.  A subsequent call to `cudaGetLastError()` will return no error, because the error 2 does not corrupt the cuda context, and is therefore not a "sticky" error.  Subsequent operations after that also return no error.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/f14i1bJU) is a fully worked example demonstrating this sequence, i.e. my understanding of the sequence outlined in the question.