# Can't restore my GPU after bad_alloc with `cudaDeviceReset()` from the CUDA library

Tags: cuda, reset, thrust

The following program does 3 successive calls to the "test" function where some thrust operations are executed. Each one of these 3 calls provides a different size to the problem:

- 3,000 for the first call;
- 300,000,000 for the second call;
- 3,000 again for the third call.

The second call is expected to fail, but the third one should be successful (as is the first one) if I properly cleaned up the status of my GPU. Unfortunately, it also fails. Moreover, successive calls would also result in a failure until I quit my process and start again.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/system_error.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

#define CUDA_CALL(x)do { if((x) != cudaSuccess) { return -11;}} while(0)

typedef typename thrust::device_vector<size_t>  tDevVecInt;
typedef typename thrust::device_vector<float>   tDevVecFlt;

struct modSim : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>  
{
    int szMat;
    int p;

    modSim(int in1, int in2)
    {
        this->p = in1;
        this->szMat = in2;
    }
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int &x) 
    {
        return (x/szMat)*p+(x%p);
    }
};

 int test(size_t szData)
{

    modSim moduloCol(3, 33);

    CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(0));

    try
    {

        tDevVecFlt devRand(szData);
        tDevVecInt devIndices(szData);
        tDevVecFlt devData(szData);

        thrust::sequence(devRand.begin(), devRand.end());
        thrust::tabulate(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.end(), moduloCol); 
        thrust::sort_by_key(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.end(), devRand.begin()); 

    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
        CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(0));
        return -3;
    }
    catch(thrust::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
        CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(0));
        return -2;
    }

    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
    return 0;   
}


int main(void)
{

    size_t n;
    int retVal;

    n = 3000;
    retVal = test(n);
    std::cout << retVal << std::endl;

    n = 300000000;
    retVal = test(n);
    std::cout << retVal << std::endl;

    n = 3000;
    retVal = test(n);
    std::cout << retVal << std::endl;


    return(0);
}
```

On my setup (Windows 8, NVIDIA GeForce 820m with 2GB dedicated VRAM, CUDA 7.0 compiled with nvcc, the command line is "$nvcc -arch=compute_20 test.cu -run" ), I get this:

- first call with N = 3,000 succeeds;
- second call with N = 300,000,000 fails with the exception `bad allocation: out of memory`;
- third call with N = 3,000 fails with a `thrust::system error : after cub_::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs(1): out of memory`.

So the output looks like this:

```
0
bad allocation: out of memory
-3
after cub_::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs(1): out of memory
-2
```

As mentioned above, the third call shouldn't have failed as it is identical to the successful first call.

This failure seems to be a consequence of the previous call (the one that issued a `bad alloc`) but I cleaned everything up after the `bad alloc` with a `cudaDeviceReset()` and a `cudaSetDevice()`.

Despite the cleaning instructions, the device is not back into a functional state and I don't understand why.

If I did something wrong, what would by the proper way to restore the GPU to a functional state after the first failure without ending my process?

Does anyone reproduce this?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using pointers to thust vectors within you `test`functions. Try the code with direct instances rather than pointers with instances. It might be that the vector destructors are not being called when you delete the pointers to them

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, this was a residual of previous tests, I edited my post following your comments unfortunately the behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has been reported to the NVIDIA issue list. The people from NVIDIA reproduced this behavior and couldn't explain it at first glance.

They however provided me with a workaround I'd like to share with whom may be interested. The idea was just to add a call to `cudaGetLastError()` when the exception is detected instead of (or in my case, before) the call to `cudaDeviceReset()`.

```
catch(std::bad_alloc &e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
    CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(0));
    return -3;
}
```

Then, after further investigations, they found out that it was not a real issue in `cudaDeviceReset()` function actually and gave me the following explanation:

> The `cudaDeviceReset()` explicitly destroys and cleans up all resources associated with the current device in the current process. It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the device is not being accessed by any other host threads from the process when this function is called. Furthermore any error by a Cuda runtime call is registered internally and can be viewed using either `cudaPeekAtLastError()` or `cudaGetLastError()`. The first can be called multiple times to read the same error, while the later is used to READ AND CLEAR the error. It is advisable to clear the earlier error before making subsequent Cuda runtime call, using `cudaGetLastError()`.

Then from this point, I found a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909368/once-cudamalloc-returns-out-of-memory-every-cuda-api-call-returns-failure/30911340#30911340) I hadn't reached before and that deals with a similar issue. The answer there is worth reading as well.